# Determining suitable zoom level based on a set of locations for OSMDroid

Tags: android, osmdroid

From Google Maps Android API v2, I understand that this can be done through this method:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (Location loc : allLocations) {
    LatLng position = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());
    builder.include(position);
}

CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), someMarginValue);
map.moveCamera(cu);
```

However I can't seem to find a way to do this for OSMDroid. Is there a solution/ class to help determine the zoom level based on a set of locations?

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.37, -119.01));
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.35, -119.01));
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.11, -118.32));
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.10, -118.32));
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.10, -118.15));
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.09, -118.14));
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.63, -117.88));
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.65, -117.72));
    waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(35.62, -117.67));

    final BoundingBoxE6 boundingBoxE6 = BoundingBoxE6.fromGeoPoints(waypoints);
    mMapView.zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBoxE6,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
    mapController.setZoom(10.0);
    map.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mapController.setCenter(boundingBox.getCenterWithDateLine());
            mapController.zoomToSpan(boundingBox.getLatitudeSpan(), boundingBox.getLongitudeSpan());
            map.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

Without the initial zoom level, it doesn't work at all. The second part, map.post can be removed but I think it is helping zoomToSpan() to be in isLayoutOccurred() state when calculates. 
You can obtain boundingBox like this:

```
final BoundingBox boundingBox = BoundingBox.fromGeoPoints(geoPoints);
```

And geoPointes is just a List of GeoPoint objects.

Answer (score 0):

In osmdroid you can determine the min/max coordinate from the set of locations and then call

```
 Mapview.zoomToBoundingBox(...)
```

to set the zoomlevel.